# Surface area above an elliptic region

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I have the following problem: Calculate the surface area of a solid contained between surfaces: $x^2 + y^2 = \frac13z^2$ and $x + y + z = 2 $.

First one is a cone and the second one is flat surface. By comparing the two equations together I get the equation of a cross section region above xy-plane which is an ellipse: $x^2 + 2x -xy + y^2 + 2y - 2 = 0$. And this is my region that I need to integrate over.

Now I need to calculate two double integrals, one for each of the given surfaces. When I calculate the integrand functions, everything seems to simplify nicely, but I struggle with the limits of integration. I would appreciate, if someone could help me, how to determine the limits of that elliptic region.

Comment: The $xy$ term in the ellipse, and the original equations for the cone and plane suggest to me that you might want to start with a change of variables, $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$. Then $u^2+v^2=\frac23z^2$ and $u+z=2$.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. With this substitution I was able to move forward and calculate both double integrals that I was looking for.